# How to sort a list by the nth class of each child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
    <div class="atr1 atr2 atr3"></div>
</div>

<button type='button' id='sort'>Sort</button>
```

I need to sort the list by nth class of each child element, by .atr2 for example.

How can that be done in jQuery or pure JS?

I've tried to put the nth class of the first child into a variable like this:

```
var atr2 = document.getElementsByClassName('atr1')[0].classList.item(1);
```

I found a code snippet that sorts the list by the text inside of each div element.

```
function sortUl(mylist) {
    var listitems = $('.container').find('div').sort();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase()); 
})
jQuery.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });    
}


$('#sort').on('click', function () {
    sortUl($('.container'));
});
```

How can this piece of code be modified to do the right job? Completely new solution would also suit my needs.

Any hints are welcome, please help me, thank you!

Comment: Relying on any particular ordering of classes would result in *extremely* fragile code.

Comment: Why not use data attributes instead of trying to sort on something arbitrary like the order of classes?

Comment: @JonUleis Ah, thank you for the hint with data attributes, I will try this approach.